# git filter-branch using two queries

Tags: git

I am trying to following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988511/remove-a-directory-from-all-previous-commits) to remove multiple files at once. Using individually the command:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch "UserFiles/*"' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

works fine. But when I try to combine 2 queries at once i get back the error `WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged`

The command I tried was:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch "testDir/*"' && 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch "UserFiles/*"' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--index-filter` argument is given to the shell via `eval`.  What this means in practice is that if you need to run two different index filters, you would spell them out as:

```
git filter-branch <args> --index-filter 'cmd1; cmd2' <more-args>
```

Note that this is a *semicolon*, not a comma, and it goes *inside* the quotes that make the expression a single argument to `--index-filter`.

In your particular case, however, your index-filter can probably<sup>1</sup> be done with *one* command.  The one command is:

```
git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch UserFiles testDir
```

When using `-r` (recursive remove), there is no need for the `/*`, hence no need for inner quotes.  Of course, as always, the command to be used for the index filter has to be passed through as a single argument, so if it contains spaces—and as we can see, it does—this *does* need the *outer* quotes.  Hence:

```
git filter-branch -f \
    --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch testDir UserFiles' \
    --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

(I broke this into three lines, the first two ending with backslash-newline, for posting purposes.  Since backslash-newline gets the shell to continue reading, they can be entered this way, or you can turn it all back into one big line without the backslashes.)

---

<sup>1</sup>If your intent is to remove only *files* within the `UserFiles` and `testDir` directories, and not to remove any subdirectories and *their* files, this "probably" is wrong.  That is:

```
git rm -r --cached testDir
```

will remove `testDir/a`, `testDir/b/c`, `testdir/b/d`, `testdir/b`, `testdir/c`, and `testdir` itself, while:

```
git rm --cached "testDir/*"
```

will remove only `testDir/a` and `testDir/c`, leaving `testDir/b/` intact.  If you need to do that, you cannot use the `-r` short-cut.

Comment: thanks. I needed to remove subdirectories as well. I don't know why mine worked but everything (except the unwanted dirs) is now pushed without the warning. I am accepting your answer however because unlike mine it explains "why".

Answer (score 0):

After randomly checking different combinations I got it. it should be like that:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch "testDir/*"', 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch "UserFiles/*"' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```