# Why does gitignore only ignore some of the paths?

Tags: git

When I check with `git check-ignore -v *` I get the following output:

```
.gitignore:7:dist       dist
.gitignore:12:node_modules      node_modules
```

And my `.gitignore`:

```
apps

# compiled output
dist
tmp
/out-tsc

# dependencies
node_modules
```

Why does it selectively ignore `dist` and `node_modules` but not `apps`? (the folder `apps` does exist)

Btw, if I move the `node_modules` to another line for example, it will immediately recognize the change

Comment: Is `.gitignroe` just a typo or the file really is `.gitignroe`? When you say "*…if I move the `node_modules` to another line for example, it will immediately recognize the change*" — who recognizes what change? Git starts to ignore `apps`? Or what?

Comment: @phd sorry yes it's a typo, will edit my post, and I mean git immediately recognize that node_modules is on another line number, by that I just mean that it does read the file for sure, but it won't recognize `apps` no matter what, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect you have files in the `apps` folder which were versioned before you actually added the path in your `.gitignore` file.

In that case the new files you add in `apps` will be ignored but the already versioned files can't be ignored (unless you rewrite history and remove them).

Here's a test session to illustrate:

```
# Create a dir to hold a test git repo
$ mkdir /tmp/testForSo
$ cd /tmp/testForSo/
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/testForSo/.git/

# Create our structure for test with two folders
$ mkdir firstDir
$ mkdir secondDir

# Create a file in firstdir and version it
$ touch firstDir/file1.txt
$ git add firstDir/file1.txt 
$ git commit -m "version file1"
[main (root-commit) 5e2e15a] version file1
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 firstDir/file1.txt

# Time to ignore both dirs
$ echo firstDir > .gitignore
$ echo secondDir >> .gitignore
$ git add .gitignore 
$ git commit -m "Ignore first and second dir"
[main 2c0de02] Ignore first and second dir
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore

# We can then create some other files inside both ignored dirs
$ touch firstDir/newfileafterignore.txt
$ touch secondDir/otherfile.txt

# If we try to debug gitignore as you did...
$ git check-ignore -v *
.gitignore:2:secondDir  secondDir

# .. as you can see only the second dir is reported as the first
# holds a file already versioned and cannot be entirely ignored.
# Note that we can still see the new file is ignored by issuing e.g.
$ git check-ignore -v */*
.gitignore:1:firstDir   firstDir/newfileafterignore.txt
.gitignore:2:secondDir  secondDir/otherfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was it
Used the suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988511/remove-a-directory-from-all-previous-commits
to re-write history and remove those commits